# Cannot load sqlite3_native.so when trying to rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-16.04, sqlite3-ruby

I'm following a tutorial of Ruby on rails from this website: https://rails-3-2.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#sec-heroku_setup

and I'm currently stuck at a part where it's telling me to run the command:

> rake assets:precompile

It's giving me this error:

> /home/myName/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
> rake aborted!
> LoadError: incompatible library version - /home/myName/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so
> /home/myName/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require' /home/myName/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in` rescue in <top (required)>'
> /home/myName/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>' /home/myName/Desktop/rails_projects/first_app/config/application.rb:7:in` <top (required)>'
> /home/myName/Desktop/rails_projects/first_app/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>' /home/myName/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-12.2.1/exe/rake:27:in` <top (required)>'
>
> Caused by:
> LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3/2.3/sqlite3_native
> /home/myName/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3.rb:4:in `require' /home/myName/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3.rb:4:in` <top (required)>'
> /home/myName/Desktop/rails_projects/first_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>' /home/myName/Desktop/rails_projects/first_app/Rakefile:5:in` <top (required)>'
> /home/myName/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rake-12.2.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
> (See full trace by running task with --trace)

From what I understand of it, I think my sqlite3 is corrupted since I made sure that sqlite3 is installed ("gem list" returns me a list of the gems installed and sqlite 1.3.5 is installed).

I therefor attempted to re-install sqlite3 1.3.5 but no luck in getting it to work. I'm confused on how to resolve the issue, any help is very much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: sqlite is correctly installed on your system?

Comment: I believe it is, when I use the command "gem list" it shows sqlite3 in the list of gems installed. Furthermore, I have tried to re-install sqlite by using the command "apt-get install sqlite".

Comment: Why are you using such an ancient version of the Rails tutorial book? Rails 3.2 was released back in 2012 and the first thing you'll have to do is catch up to 10 years of changes.

Comment: That's the version my workplace's using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow fixed it.

I'm not exactly sure why it worked but it seems like it worked after re-installing bundler.

```
gem uninstall bundler

gem install bundler
```